# Displaying a tree in schema with CSS

Tags: html, css

First of all, sorry for my english, it is not perfect. I have a tree ordered in ul lists, something like this (it is dinamic):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Level 1
            <ul>
                <li>Item level 2</li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>
        Level 1
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Item level 2
                        <ul>
                            <li>Item level 3</li>
                            <li>Item level 3</li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    Item level 2
                </li>
                <li>
                    Item level 2
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the result I would like:

http://oi48.tinypic.com/dpgt4p.jpg

I would like to join each father with its son with lines. I know how to display each div correctly with display:table, display:cell, etc... But I have no idea about how to draw those lines with css for joining the divs.

Has anybody any idea or suggestion please? I would like to combine HTML + CSS or any solution with Javascript.

Have you ever seen before something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a CSS only approach. It's a not a fully working example but maybe it helps you to get into the right direction.

I used this background image to connect the items: [image] This must be improved, as it doesn't work solely when there are multiple child elements on a sibling.

**CSS**

```
ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    left: 115px;
}

ul > li {
    position: relative;
}

ul > li > ul {
    margin-top: -18px;
}

ul > li > ul > li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: -31px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 5px;
    background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2mLf.png) no-repeat 0 -10px;
}

ul > li > ul > li:first-child:before {
    top: 10px;
    left: -21px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 1px;
    background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2mLf.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/B85SP/)

Comment: Great job, I know css but I am not an expert. This is a very good example, I will try to follow this direction. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsPlumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/jquery/demo.html) as an add on to jQuery. It will allow you to plumb the elements together, or for a slightly more simple solution take a look at [raphaels example](http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html).